# How to set header text color in android timepicker dialog's manual input mode dialog(descendent dialog)?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have a time picker (image attached) and a keyboard icon is displayed. When keyboard icon is clicked a simple dialog is shown, in which time is entered manually using keyboard. What attribute is to be used for setting the header text color(which is always white)? ("Set Time")

Any clue/leads to change the color of "Set Time" header text please?[image: This is the manual input dialog]

[This is sample time picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZmXu.png)

Code to show the time picker:

```
public void showTimePicker(@NonNull final Object timePickerTime, final boolean isRangeType) {
```

{
final int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

```
final int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 

TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), new TimeSetListener((ObservableField) timePickerTime, isRangeType), hour, minutes, true); 

timePickerDialog.show();
```

}

// Time picker style applied:

```css
  <style name="UIDTimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orange_level_30</item> <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/aqua_level_30</item> <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_level_30</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/green_level_30</item> 
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray_level_80</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray_level_45 </item>
</style>
```

Comment: Add your code which u are using for showing the Dialog

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69642305/edit) your question and add the code with question .